# get the records for the latest timestamp mysql

Tags: php, mysql

how do I get all the records for latest date. The date filed in my db is called recordEntryDate and it is in this form 2010-01-26 13:28:35

Lang: php
DB: mysql

Comment: Do you have an index on `recordEntryDate`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE DATE(recordEntryDate) = (
   SELECT MAX(DATE(recordEntryDate))
   FROM table1
)
```

Note that this query won't be able to take advantage of an index on `recordEntryDate`. If you have a lot of rows this similar query might be faster for you:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE recordEntryDate >= (
   SELECT DATE(MAX(recordEntryDate))
   FROM table1
)
```

Comment: doing this but its not working

SELECT
     table.*,
     u.initials AS initals
     FROM
      database1.mytable AS table
     JOIN
      database.user AS u
     ON
      u.userID = table.userid
     WHERE
      id = 12548
     
     AND 
      recordEntryDate = ( SELECT MAX(DATE(recordEntryDate)) from {database1.myrable ) ";

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
WHERE DATE(recordEntryDate) = ( 
   SELECT MAX((recordEntryDate))
   FROM table1 
)
```

Didn't need `DATE` there.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you want todays results

```
SELECT * 
FROM  table 
WHERE  recordEntryDate > DATE( NOW( ) )
```