# mysql get latest records by timestamp without subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp, greatest-n-per-group

In this table i have four column

```
id   state_id   state        add_time
1       10         1        1385461144
2       12         3        1385461144
3       14         2        1385461144
4       12         5        1385461264
5       10         2        1385461264
```

i want to get latest records by last field (add_time)

the result must be like this

```
id   state_id   state        add_time
3       14         2        1385461144
4       12         5        1385461264
5       10         2        1385461264
```

i found this question [get the records for the latest timestamp mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693408/get-the-records-for-the-latest-timestamp-mysql)
and it uses two select query (subquery). but i don't want to use subquery.

is there any other way to get latest records?

Comment: What is wrong with sub-queries?

Comment: i think it's slower than other way.

Comment: `INNER JOIN` or use function like `MAX(add_time)` :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 approaches to get the results you're looking for.

Left join solution:

```
SELECT t1.* FROM t t1
LEFT JOIN t t2
ON t1.state_id = t2.state_id AND t1.add_time < t2.add_time
WHERE t2.add_time IS NULL
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/94393/1).

Subquery solution:

```
SELECT t1.* FROM t t1
JOIN (
  SELECT state_id, max(add_time) add_time FROM t
  GROUP BY state_id
) t2
ON t1.state_id = t2.state_id AND t1.add_time = t2.add_time
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6a17dd/1).

Both will output:

```
| ID | STATE_ID | STATE |   ADD_TIME |
|----|----------|-------|------------|
|  3 |       14 |     2 | 1385461144 |
|  4 |       12 |     5 | 1385461264 |
|  5 |       10 |     2 | 1385461264 |
```

Comment: Most likely the second one. But I'd recommend you give both a try and see :)

Comment: I doubt if the first one is faster!

Comment: @MostyMostacho i want to create View from this query but views cannot created from sub query after from. now i should use the first one, can you suggest any other way like second one?

Comment: I would go for the first one, then. The other option is to create an intermediate view for the inner select and then replace the inner select for that view but that would most likely decrease performance

Comment: The second one is orders of magnitude faster than the first.

Answer (score 1):

while you're at it to test which one is faster, here's another one to try
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/760c73/13/0

```
SELECT id,state_id,state,add_time
  FROM t t1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
      (SELECT 1 
       FROM t t2
       WHERE t2.state_id = t1.state_id
       AND t2.add_time > t1.add_time);
```

Comment: Thanks, i will test this as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you are synching the data with a client (Browser or a app), for each call set a parameter for specifying the last synch time(somthing like lastSyncTime) and based on this query your database. For the first call set the parameter lastSyncTime = 0 in your logic and for the subsequent calls use the MAX(ADD_TIME). These calculation must be at your client side. And in your server you need to get the parameter lastSyncTime and do a query something like this

```
SELECT id, state_id, state, add_time FROM tabname WHERE add_time > lastSyncTime
```

So your server and db server not have much load.

Comment: thanks, but i'm not syncing data, i store new states every 5 minutes and want get latest states by add_time in my table.

Comment: @M2sh OK then go for the JOIN